# foundation-icons-sass-rails icons are not showing near button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation-5

I followed all of the instructions for the foundation-icons-sass-rails gem including importing and precompiling the gem's assets. But, for some reason the icons are not showing on my foundation button. I will show you the line of code. What exactly am I missing here?

```
<button href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false" class="button dropdown [radius] zurb-button-custom"><i class="fi-[eye]"></i>Profile</button><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

The icon for eye is:

```
<i class="fi-eye"></i>
```